# Why do grids have spacings in the compiled application?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

See screenshots below:

In the Visual Studio designer:
[image: in the Visual Studio designer]

In the compiled program:
[image: in the compiled program]

XAML MainWindow code:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Audience.MainWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                      Title="Carbide Audience" TitleCharacterCasing="Normal"
                      TitleForeground="#ADC7FA" Deactivated="MainWindow_OnDeactivated" Activated="MainWindow_OnActivated"
                      ShowIconOnTitleBar="False" ShowSystemMenuOnRightClick="False"
                      WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
                      ResizeMode="CanMinimize"
                      Height="530" Width="900">

    <Controls:MetroWindow.TitleTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                       TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Margin="8 -1 8 0"
                                       FontWeight="DemiBold"
                                       FontSize="14">
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Controls:MetroWindow.TitleTemplate>

    <Grid>
        <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="437" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="894">
            <TabItem Header="TabItem">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="62" Margin="0,442,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="894" Background="#3372F2">

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

Also, I'm using MahApps.Metro, maybe problem is in it.

Comment: Please add the window XAML.

Comment: Added, but it seems to me that there is nothing supernatural in it.

Comment: I think we'll need the rest of the XAML, not just the grid. It looks like there's some padding or margin on the window that holds the grid.

Comment: Okay, I posted the full XAML file now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying way too much in terms of sizing both the window and its content - set the window size and let the child controls expand to fill the available space. Using Margin to position controls within a grid is also unnecessary, just set the row definitions of the parent grid as appropriate, and assign each child control to its own row.

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Audience.MainWindow"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                  Title="Carbide Audience" TitleCharacterCasing="Normal"
                  TitleForeground="#ADC7FA" Deactivated="MainWindow_OnDeactivated" Activated="MainWindow_OnActivated"
                  ShowIconOnTitleBar="False" ShowSystemMenuOnRightClick="False"
                  WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
                  ResizeMode="CanMinimize"
                  Height="530" Width="900">

<Controls:MetroWindow.TitleTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Margin="8 -1 8 0"
                                   FontWeight="DemiBold"
                                   FontSize="14">
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</Controls:MetroWindow.TitleTemplate>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>      

    <TabControl Grid.Row="0">
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

   <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="#3372F2">

   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Agreed - OP has set the control width to 900 and the other items to 894, leaving a gap.